# Encriptar RSA en C# desencriptar en java

Tags: java, c#, encriptación

Estoy construyendo dos aplicaciones una en `C#` y otra en Java, las cuales harán uso de `RSA` como parte de la encripcion y desencripcion que debe manejar.

Cuando encripto con java y desencripto en `c#` funciona perfecto, el problema es cuando encripto en `c#` y voy a desencriptar en java me arroja :

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than
>   64 bytes

Estoy usando `RSA` con 512 como tamaño para generar las claves en ambos lados, si aumento a 1048 el error cambia a el tamaño no debe se mayor a 128.

Copio las clases con los metodos con los cuales estoy trabajando :

Java :

```
public String decrypt(String message, RSAPrivateKey key) {
    try {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] dataEncripted =Base64.decodeBase64(message.getBytes());
        byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(dataEncripted);
        return new String(data,"UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

C#  :

```
public static string Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
    {
        var sb = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
            byte[] encryptedByteArray;
            byte[] dataToEncrypt;

                dataToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
                sb = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedByteArray);


        }
```

Lo que he notado es que en el proceso que me funciona de `java` --> `c#` cuando encripto el arreglo de bits que se genera va de 0 a 63 osea 64 bits, pero en el proceso contrario `c#` --> `java` el dato encriptado es un arreglo de bits que genera `c#` va de 0 a 64 osea 65 `bits`.

Como podría hacer para que en `c#` el `RSA Provider` me genere un arreglo de `bytes` igual que en `java`, o como podría solucionar este problema?.

Comment: los bytes en c# y java se manejan diferente, en c# los bytes van de 0 a 255, mientras que en java de -128 a 127, ambos lenguajes del 0 al 127 representan el mismo valor, pero en C# los numero menores a 0 se representan con valores superior a 127, ejemplo:  c# 128 = java -1, esto para los tipo bytes. adicionalmente antes de pasar los bytes a string64 compara los arreglos de bytes, ya que veo que los encoding utiliados son diferentes, y recuerdo haber leido en algun sitio , que por lo menos para el caso del utf-16, el resultado no es el mismo  ya que java usaba  big-endian y c# usa little-endian

Answer (score 2):

Verifica las llaves ya que podria ser problema de como las estan almacenando o leyendo

Este es un ejemplo que te podría servir

Java, esta hecho con bouncy castle

```
package javaapplication1;

import static com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.OutputFormat.Defaults.Encoding;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.*;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PrivateKeyInfoFactory;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;


public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,    NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException {
     //String de prueba encriptado en C#, las llaves las genere en c# tambien

     String hola = "3ges2OQM8SNQimvZc8LrKbtgRhXutgWj7U9QpLYLRFNmlC12FqZoS/RcHMRZ4nj/AGmBbWRqSJW8060FLKUgCszXs4K54Rhy0+P09WADPI9WJZAsPySbEboqhQldqFroXYQciGY67hzafGhtQmY04ig8/s66n/zymnXeyV34/sg=";
        String filename = "\\private.Key.PEM";

        PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
            PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
            byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
            PrivateKey privateKeyJ = factory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
            System.out.println(decrypt(hola, (RSAPrivateKey) privateKeyJ));
        } finally {
            pemReader.close();
        }    
        System.in.read();    
    }

    public static String decrypt(String message, RSAPrivateKey key) {
        try {

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] dataEncripted = Base64.decode(message.getBytes());
            byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(dataEncripted);
            return new String(data, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

***** C# en este código de consola se crean y almacenan las llaves en archivos

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            JavaKey(rsa);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
            ExportPrivateKey(rsa, new StringWriter(sb));
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("private.Key.PEM", sb.ToString());

            string pubkey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("public.Key.cs.xml"); //rsa.ToXmlString(false);
            string prikey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("private.Key.cs.xml"); //rsa.ToXmlString(true);

            var encr = Encrypt("hola", pubkey);
            Console.WriteLine(encr);
             Console.WriteLine(Dencrypt(encr      , prikey));

        }
        public static string Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
        {
            var sb = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
                byte[] encryptedByteArray;
                byte[] dataToEncrypt;

                dataToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
                sb = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedByteArray);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return sb;
        }
        public static string Dencrypt(string data, string privateKey)
        {
            var sb = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
                byte[] encryptedByteArray;
                byte[] dataToEncrypt;

                dataToEncrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                encryptedByteArray = rsa.Decrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
                sb = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedByteArray);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return sb;
        }


        private static void JavaKey(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa)
        {           
           string serializedPublic = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
            string serializedPrivate = rsa.ToXmlString(true);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("public.Key.cs.xml", serializedPublic);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("private.Key.cs.xml", serializedPrivate);
        }


        #region http://stackoverflow.com/a/23739932/890839
        private static void ExportPrivateKey(RSACryptoServiceProvider csp, TextWriter outputStream)
        {
            if (csp.PublicOnly) throw new ArgumentException("CSP does not contain a private key", "csp");
            var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(true);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                writer.Write((byte)0x30); // SEQUENCE
                using (var innerStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var innerWriter = new BinaryWriter(innerStream);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, new byte[] { 0x00 }); // Version
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Modulus);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Exponent);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.D);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.P);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Q);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DP);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DQ);
                    EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.InverseQ);
                    var length = (int)innerStream.Length;
                    EncodeLength(writer, length);
                    writer.Write(innerStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
                }

                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length).ToCharArray();
                outputStream.WriteLine("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
                // Output as Base64 with lines chopped at 64 characters
                for (var i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += 64)
                {
                    outputStream.WriteLine(base64, i, Math.Min(64, base64.Length - i));
                }
                outputStream.WriteLine("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
            }
        }

        private static void EncodeLength(BinaryWriter stream, int length)
        {
            if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "Length must be non-negative");
            if (length < 0x80)
            {
                // Short form
                stream.Write((byte)length);
            }
            else
            {
                // Long form
                var temp = length;
                var bytesRequired = 0;
                while (temp > 0)
                {
                    temp >>= 8;
                    bytesRequired++;
                }
                stream.Write((byte)(bytesRequired | 0x80));
                for (var i = bytesRequired - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    stream.Write((byte)(length >> (8 * i) & 0xff));
                }
            }
        }

        private static void EncodeIntegerBigEndian(BinaryWriter stream, byte[] value, bool forceUnsigned = true)
        {
            stream.Write((byte)0x02); // INTEGER
            var prefixZeros = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (value[i] != 0) break;
                prefixZeros++;
            }
            if (value.Length - prefixZeros == 0)
            {
                EncodeLength(stream, 1);
                stream.Write((byte)0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (forceUnsigned && value[prefixZeros] > 0x7f)
                {
                    // Add a prefix zero to force unsigned if the MSB is 1
                    EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros + 1);
                    stream.Write((byte)0);
                }
                else
                {
                    EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros);
                }
                for (var i = prefixZeros; i < value.Length; i++)
                {
                    stream.Write(value[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenté reproducir tu problema, pero me ha sido imposible.

Cuando encripto algo obtengo los 64 bytes que se deben obtener.

```
var data = "123";
var sb = string.Empty;
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);

byte[] encryptedByteArray;
byte[] dataToEncrypt;

dataToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false); // Tiene 64bytes. rsa.KeySize / 8
sb = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedByteArray);
```

Veo dos puntos débiles al código:

- En c# estás usando como codificación ASCII y en Java UTF8. Deberías usar la misma.
- En Java los bytes están ordenados al revés que en c# posiblemente tengas que hacer un Array.Reverse http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html

Espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Desafortunadamente, C# no proporciona ninguna manera simple de hacer esto. Pero esto va a decodificar correctamente una clave pública x509 (asegúrese de base 64 descodificar el parámetro x509key primero).

Esta solución fija el tamaño de la clave que se va a utilizar en bits.

```
public static string EncryptRsa(string stringPublicKey, string stringDataToEncrypt)
    {
        byte[] publicKey = Convert.FromBase64String(stringPublicKey);
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = DecodeX509PublicKey(publicKey))
        {
            byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringDataToEncrypt);
            byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }
    }

    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeX509PublicKey(byte[] x509key)
    {
        byte[] SeqOID = { 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(x509key);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(ms);

        if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x30)
            ReadASNLength(reader); //skip the size 
        else
            return null;

        int identifierSize = 0; //total length of Object Identifier section 
        if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x30)
            identifierSize = ReadASNLength(reader);
        else
            return null;

        if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x06) //is the next element an object identifier? 
        {
            int oidLength = ReadASNLength(reader);
            byte[] oidBytes = new byte[oidLength];
            reader.Read(oidBytes, 0, oidBytes.Length);
            if (oidBytes.SequenceEqual(SeqOID) == false) //is the object identifier rsaEncryption PKCS#1? 
                return null;

            int remainingBytes = identifierSize - 2 - oidBytes.Length;
            reader.ReadBytes(remainingBytes);
        }

        if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x03) //is the next element a bit string? 
        {
            ReadASNLength(reader); //skip the size 
            reader.ReadByte(); //skip unused bits indicator 
            if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x30)
            {
                ReadASNLength(reader); //skip the size 
                if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x02) //is it an integer? 
                {
                    int modulusSize = ReadASNLength(reader);
                    byte[] modulus = new byte[modulusSize];
                    reader.Read(modulus, 0, modulus.Length);
                    if (modulus[0] == 0x00) //strip off the first byte if it's 0 
                    {
                        byte[] tempModulus = new byte[modulus.Length - 1];
                        Array.Copy(modulus, 1, tempModulus, 0, modulus.Length - 1);
                        modulus = tempModulus;
                    }

                    if (reader.ReadByte() == 0x02) //is it an integer? 
                    {
                        int exponentSize = ReadASNLength(reader);
                        byte[] exponent = new byte[exponentSize];
                        reader.Read(exponent, 0, exponent.Length);

                        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
                        RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
                        RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
                        RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;
                        RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
                        return RSA;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static int ReadASNLength(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        //Note: this method only reads lengths up to 4 bytes long as 
        //this is satisfactory for the majority of situations. 
        int length = reader.ReadByte();
        if ((length & 0x00000080) == 0x00000080) //is the length greater than 1 byte 
        {
            int count = length & 0x0000000f;
            byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
            reader.Read(lengthBytes, 4 - count, count);
            Array.Reverse(lengthBytes); // 
            length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
        }
        return length;
    }
```